# Elements not where they are supposed to be (tables)

Tags: html, css

[I want the elements in the red boxes to be in the blue boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rxPH.png)

```html
  <table>
    <tr style="">
      <td style="text-align: center; width: 70%;" colspan="2"><img src="pre_header.jpg" alt="" style="width: 70%"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="">
      <td><img style="width: 35%;" src="logo.jpg" alt=""></td>
      <td><p style="width: 35%;">Monday 16<sup>th</sup> of december 2019 <br> Volume 5</p></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

the code above is for a table the pre-header is centred perfectly but the logo and logo description just don't want to go where they are supposed to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving your styles around, specifically: treat each element like a container or a box.

```
<table style="width:70%;margin:0 auto;>
    <tr style="margin:0;border:none;padding:0;">
      <td colspan="2"><img src="pre_header.jpg" alt="" style="width: 100%"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="margin:0;padding:0;border:none;">
      <td style="width:35%;margin-left:0;"><img style="width: 100%" src="logo.jpg" alt=""></td>
      <td style="width:35%;clear:right;margin-right:0;"><p>Monday 16<sup>th</sup> of december 2019 <br> Volume 5</p></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

That may require some tweaks, but it should be pretty close. Specifically keep an eye on that 'clear'.

Comment: I have a question how did you get those tds to be separate boxes i could not do that

Comment: @flameskull2001 the trs are rows that span the full width of the table.  The tds inside them would normally fill the row, but I specified a width of 35% for each one, which doesn't add up to 100%.  Things within the row I spec'd left-align so the left box is taken care of.  Clear seems to override text align and send it all the way to the right. I'm glad it helped :)